# why the customer data is not read? How can I correct this problem?

Tags: angular

I am having a problem updating the data of a certain client.
I have a table where the customer's name and email are listed; on each customer it is possible to delete it or update it.
The moment I click on the Update button, I get a window with the related fields to be able to modify them (id is of type hidden of course).
Once I edit these fields, when I click the "Confirm update" button I notice that the id, customer_name and customer_email fields are all set to null.
However, these fields are passed in the updateCust method.

customer-list.component.html

```js
div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Customers</h1><br>
    <div class="row" [hidden]="!deleteMessage">

      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
          <strong>Customer Data Deleted</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Customer Email</th>
          <th>Action</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">
          <td>{{customer.customer_name}}</td>
          <td>{{customer.customer_email}}</td>
          <td><button (click)="deleteCustomer(customer.customer_id)" class='btn btn-primary'><i
                class="fa fa-futboll-0">Delete</i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(editProfileModal, customer)" >Update</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody><br>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #editProfileModal let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
   <h5 class="modal-title" id="editProfileLabel">Edit Profile</h5>
   <button type="button" class="close" (click)="modal.dismiss()" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal-body">
   <form [formGroup]="editProfileForm" (ngSubmit)="updateCust()">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" formControlName="customer_id" id="customer_name">
    <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="name" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Customer Name</label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="customer_name" id="customer_name">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Customer Email</label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="customer_email" id="customer_email">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [hidden]="isupdated">Confirm update</button>  
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="changeisUpdate()">Close</button> 
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </ng-template>
```

customer-list.component.ts

```js
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerService } from '../customer.service';
import { Customer } from '../customer';
import { Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'app-customer-list',
templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.css']
})
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit {
editProfileForm!: FormGroup;

constructor(private customerservice: CustomerService, private fb: FormBuilder, private modalService: NgbModal) {}

customersArray: any[] = [];
dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

customers: Customer[] = [];
customer: Customer = new Customer();
deleteMessage = false;
customerlist: any;
isupdated = false;


ngOnInit() {
};
this.customerservice.getCustomerList().subscribe(data => {
console.log(data)
this.customers = data;
this.dtTrigger.next();
})
this.editProfileForm = this.fb.group({
customer_id: [''],
customer_name: [''],
customer_email: ['']
});
}

openModal(targetModal: any, customer: any) {
this.modalService.open(targetModal, {
centered: true,
backdrop: 'static'
});

this.editProfileForm!.patchValue({
customer_id:customer.customer_id,
customer_name: customer.customer_name,
customer_email: customer.customer_email
});
}

customerupdateform = new FormGroup({
customer_id: new FormControl(),
customer_name: new FormControl(),
customer_email: new FormControl()
});

updateCust() {
this.customer = new Customer();
this.customer.customer_id = this.CustomerId?.value;
this.customer.customer_name = this.CustomerName?.value;
this.customer.customer_email = this.CustomerEmail?.value;
console.log(this.customer);


this.customerservice.updateCustomer(this.customer.customer_id!,this.customer).subscribe(
data => {
this.isupdated = true;
this.customerservice.getCustomerList().subscribe(data => {
this.customers = data
})
},
error => console.log(error));
}

get CustomerName() {
return this.customerupdateform.get('customer_name');
}

get CustomerEmail() {
return this.customerupdateform.get('customer_email');
}

get CustomerId() {
return this.customerupdateform.get('customer_id');
}

changeisUpdate() {
this.isupdated = false;
}
}
```

Comment: Please stick with one question rather than [posting the same code over and over again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67256627/why-is-id-not-recognized#comment118880986_67256890).

Comment: Ok I'll learn for next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
updateCust() {
this.customer = new Customer();
this.customer.customer_id = this.editProfileForm.value.customer_id;
this.customer.customer_name = this.editProfileForm.value_name;
this.customer.customer_email = this.editProfileForm.value_email;
console.log(this.customer);
```

Try this